# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number for imaplib.IMAP4_SSL

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, imap, imaplib

I am trying to read emails from a certain email address and I have figured that using imaplib is the way to go.

However, I am struggling with authenticating, which seems to be coming from having the wrong SSL version. When I try the following:

```
import imaplib, ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host, port=port, ssl_context=context)
mail.login(user, pw)
mail.list()
```

I receive the error:

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number

I asked my Admin had he said that this particular email address is running on:

- **Server Exchange 2013**
- **For TLS is 1.0 , 1.1 , 1.2 enabled**
- **For SSL is  3.0  enabled**

I therefore tried to change

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3) # returned AttributeError
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```

but that still returned the same errors.

Comment: You did read the warnings and caveats in the [documentation?](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)  Probably your SSL library was compiled with this protocol disabled (for good reason).

Comment: Hmm will contact my admin to see if he can change it. Is there in the meantime a way to compile it with this protocol enabled?

Comment: Nontrivial if you are not a C programmer but yes, of course you can recompile it if you need this. Perhaps getting the admin to switch to an SSL version which is not actively despised as insecure is the best way forward, though.

Comment: SSLv3 is twenty years old. It'll always be compiled in, but might be configured out in the server and/or client. What you want is TLSvsomething. IIRC python's default is to use the latest version that's possible.

Comment: Can you clarify on that TLSvsomething?I tried indeed the TLS protocols but they didnt work. Updated my question.

Comment: @JohnAndrew Please provide some of your configuration.  Are you sure you're using the right port?  Are you able to connect to `imap.gmail.com`, as a point of reference?

Comment: Yes gmail is possible. Port is correct too

Comment: Is there a way to check which version should be the correct one?

Comment: This can be caused by connecting to a plaintext port (eg, server admin configured it as STARTTLS, and TLS).  Are you using port 993?  Can you telnet/netcat/socat to it?  eg, do you see a banner if you do socat STDIN TCP:server.com:port and/or do you see a banner if you do socat STDIN SSL:server.com:port